# How to do add a select into a where in ZF2?

Tags: php, select, zend-framework, where-clause

First of all, hello there !=)

I was wondering if anyone knew how to write a select in a where such as

```
SELECT my_column
FROM my_table
WHERE field_1 = something
AND field_2 = ( SELECT field_2
                FROM my_table_2
                WHERE my_field = $myParam );
```

I know how to write this query without the select :

```
//This part shouldn't matter, it's just my way of connecting to table database
$select = $mytable1->getTableGateway()->getSQL()->select();

//This is where the fun begin
$select->colunms(array('my_column'))
       ->where(array('field_1' => 'something', 'field_2' => ??);
```

TRY 1 :
Using another variable that allows me to connect to the other base doesn't seem to work because of course it's not a array or anything...

```
$select_2 = $myTable2->tableGateway->getSQL()->select();

$select_2->colunms(array('field_2'))
         ->where(array('my_field' => $myParam);
$select->colunms(array('my_column'))
       ->where(array('field_1' => 'something', 'field_2' => $select_2);
```

I tried adding something like :

```
$var= $myTable2->getTableGateway()->selectWith($select_2);
//and then
$select->colunms(array('my_column'))
       ->where(array('field_1' => 'something', 'field_2' => $var->toArray());
```

It doesn't work either, because of course it's not one line...

I don't think a foreach is really necessary

Any thought before i go too far in my thoughts ?
Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ZF1 it works like this:

```
$select_2 = $myTable2->tableGateway->getSQL()->select();

$select_2->columns(array('field_2'))
         ->where(array('my_field = ?' => $myParam);
$select->columns(array('my_column'))
       ->where(array('field_1 = ?' => 'something', 'field_2 = ?' => $select_2)
```

Honestly, I'm not sure if it'll work in ZF2, but try to add the wildcard '?' to your where clause.

Best,

Comment: This actually worked... Don't know what went wrong when I tried this the first time... Thanks a lot =D